# What are the limitations for TFS 2015 Express

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm trying to figure out the differences between the TFS 2015 Express and standard license. But I can get only find documentation on the differences for 2012 and 2013.

Can anyone help me out in figuring out the limitations of TFS 2015 Express Edition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One can download [TFS Express 2015 Update 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49995).

TFS Express 2013 version’s pros and cons still apply to TFS 2015. Like below:

Pro’s

- Free
- Data stays inside your network
- Comes with version control repository
- Work item tracking
- Build Automation
- You have more control compared to the TFS Service
- Can customize Process and Workitems template
- CAL’s can be purchased in case your team grows beyond 5 users
- Support for express versions of Visual Studio

Con’s

- Must have own hardware or virtual machine
- Not accessible from anywhere
- Supports Basic installation only
- Limited Agile Project management features and tools
- No Reporting Integration
- No SharePoint Integration
- Supports only SQL Server Express Edition
- Installed on one machine. Can’t scale out
- Doesn’t support TFS Proxy
- Excludes Preemptive analytics add-on
- Need to manage your own database backups and downtimes in case of
  hardware failure
- Buy license for the Operating System and CALs if required

See also: https://lajak.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/tfs-2012-versions-of-team-foundation-server/